# What does the new `branch` argument mean in git.latest states, and how do I use it?

Tags: git, salt-stack

We just recently upgraded from Salt 2014.7 to 2015.8, and I’m confused by the new behavior in the [`git.latest`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.git.html#salt.states.git.latest) state, namely the new `branch` argument.

In our staging environments, we’re accustomed to deploying to a named branch, which the `git.latest state` obtains off the pillar and plops into the `rev` argument. Something like this:

```
{% set branch = salt['pillar.get']('myapp:branch', 'master') %}
{% set code_prefix = "/tmp/myapp" %}

{{ code_prefix }}:
  file.directory:
    - user: myapp
    - group: myapp

myapp-repo:
  git.latest:
    - name: git@github.com:MyOrg/myrepo.git
    - rev: {{ branch }}
    - force_checkout: true
    - force_clone: true
    - force_fetch: true
    - force_reset: true
    - target: {{ code_prefix }}
    - user: myapp
    - require:
        - file: {{ code_prefix }}
```

After the upgrade, we started getting weird git errors in some repos; I’m not sure exactly what’s causing the errors, but it seems to be related to the new behavior where the `rev` of the working directory changes but the local named branch doesn’t change and so it mismatches the remote version of the local branch.

Long story short, setting the `branch` argument to `git.latest` seems to solve the problem:

```
myapp-repo:
  git.latest:
    - name: git@github.com:MyOrg/myrepo.git
    - rev: {{ branch }}
    - branch: {{ branch }}
    - force_checkout: true
    - force_clone: true
    - force_fetch: true
    - force_reset: true
    - target: {{ code_prefix }}
    - user: myapp
    - require:
        - file: {{ code_prefix }}
```

But I’m wondering: why do I suddenly need the `branch` argument? What’s going to happen if I ever deploy a sha or a tag instead of a branch name?

Should I be concerned? Am I Doing It Wrong™?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `branch` parameter specifies which branch to use in the destination to checkout the `rev` branch/tag/commit. If you do not use this parameter, the `rev` will be checked out in whatever branch was active in the destination.

The documentation is pretty clear about that, I think:

> Name of the branch into which to checkout the specified rev. If not
>   specified, then Salt will not care what branch is being used locally
>   and will just use whatever branch is currently there.
>
> **Note:** If not specified, this means that the local branch name will not
>   be changed if the repository is reset to another branch/tag/SHA1.

I don't know what was the previous behaviour. Now if you checkout a commit or a tag without specifying a local branch, there will be a hard reset of the local checked out branch to the specified `rev`, regardless of its previous state (provided you use `force_reset=True`)

Personally, I use a local branch name that is not present in the distant repository, so that there is no confusion about what is checked out.

Comment: Using an unrelated branch name appears to work. The problems I was running into appear to be a bug w/ `git.latest` and git 1.7. I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/31229).